# How to get multiple namespace definions in the root element using Java?

Tags: java, xml

I am trying to create an XML DOM file using JAVA with multiple namespace definitions in the root element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xmi:XMI xmi:version="2.1" 
 xmlns:uml="http://schema.omg.org/spec/UML/2.1"
 xmlns:xmi="http://schema.omg.org/spec/XMI/2.1" 
 xmlns:cns="http://www.w3c.org/2016/XML/cns">
    <!--- lots of data -->
</xmi:XMI>
```

I've tried several methods and haven't found the correct one.

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
    Document doc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
    Element root = doc.createElementNS("http://schema.omg.org/spec/UML/2.1", "xmi:XMI");
    doc.appendChild(root);
```

creates my first namespace definition.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xmi:XMI xmlns:xmi="http://schema.omg.org/spec/XMI/2.1">
    <!--- some data -->
</xmi:XMI>
```

But how to create the others? I have experiented with `root.setAttributeNS("http://schema.omg.org/spec/UML/2.1", "uml:Model", null);`, but then I only get

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xmi:XMI 
  xmlns:uml="http://schema.omg.org/spec/UML/2.1" 
  uml:Model="" 
  xmlns:xmi="http://schema.omg.org/spec/XML/2.1"/>
    <!--- some data -->
</xmi:XMI>
```

The `uml:Model` attribute should not be there. Anyone ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
root.setAttribute("xmlns:uml", "http://schema.omg.org/spec/UML/2.1");
root.setAttribute("xmlns:cns", "http://www.w3c.org/2016/XML/cns");
```

I.e. just set them as if they were plain attributes.